# Java - save and/or retrieve a byte from an sql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays

[image: This is my java code which includes the sql which is executed]

[image: This is the sql code that originally created the table]

I know at the moment, the password is just saved as it is in the database,
but I want it to be saved as an encrypted byte array (e.g. [@7aC&s ).
I have the password set as a varbinary, but when I tried to save the password as a byte[] using the getBytes() method, it retrieved the [@7aC&s as a String and not a byte[].
I want to do this so I can then use the new String(byte[]) to decrypt it back into a String.

How can I do this, or can I not do it at all?
**EDIT:**
If you're wondering what the new MySQLConnnector(); is, here it is:
[image: MySQLConnector.java]

Comment: **Please, see how to use a `PreparedStatement` to prevent SQL injection !!** Other important point on SO, don't post your code as an image, copy paste the code as an [mcve]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not concatenate your query and some user input. This is an open door for SQL injection. You need to use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to safely insert data (read the page linked to have a full review on that part).

`PreparedStatement` provide a [`setBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBytes%28int,%20byte[]%29) method that allow you to insert a `byte[]` as a value.

> Sets the designated parameter to the given Java array of bytes. The driver converts this to an SQL VARBINARY or LONGVARBINARY (depending on the argument's size relative to the driver's limits on VARBINARY values) when it sends it to the database.

Here is a quick **and untested code** using a dummy table.

```
String sql = "insert into mytable(bytearray) values (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setBytes(1, "MyPassword".getBytes());
ps.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a PreparedStatement and use setBytes (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBytes-int-byte:A-). However, I would advise you to read up on security before rolling your own. 25 bytes is way to short for a password and as it stands your code is wide open to SQL injection. Have a look at https://projects.spring.io/spring-security, for example, which provides tested code for these things.